# Running roscore and roslaunch from eclipse

Tags: roslaunch, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run roslaunch or roscore as an External Tool following another post, but I got an error. Looks like you probably need to define for eclipse the ROS environment variables, I think I've done so, but then I get this error when running the External Tool:

```
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory
```

I think it is probably a matter of configuring the ROS environment variables for eclipse.
I've set ROS_ROOT, ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and ROS_MASTER_URI, are there any more?

Maybe there is another reason.

I would be grateful if anyone can shed some light on this.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44032/running-roscore-and-roslaunch-from-eclipse/) by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-18**:
Are you starting eclipse from a shell or via a starter? Does it work, when starting it from a shell?

**Comment by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on 2012-09-18**:
It seems to work as you suggest, running eclipse from a shell, thank you very much
However, I do not get the output in the eclipse console, a Progress Information eclipse window dialog appears instead and keeps saying "launching roslaunch"
checking from a shell I see that the ROS system is up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might need to source the `setup.bash` file from `~/.bash_profile` to make ROS environment variables available to all the system not only to `bash` session. The `~/.bash_profile` shell script is called only once when you log in, contrary to ~/.bashrc which is executed locally every time a new terminal window is opened.

P.S. Another useful approach to debug nodes started via launch files is to attach `gdb` to already running process. I am using this a lot and it is quite handy. The only problem is that you will not be able to debug any startup code, e.g. constructors, with such approach.

To use this option go to `Run->Debug Configurations...` and double-click on `C/C++ Attach to Application`. Then fill in `C/C++ Application` and press `Debug`.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0